# Ionic-app-scripts not found error after installing Ionic cordova in-app-browser plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I'm following the instructions in this link: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/

After installing the Cordova plugin and Ionic native in app browser library, running ionic cordova build android results in error: ionic-app-scripts not found.

How can I solve this issue? I have tried removing node_modules folder and run npm install and it didn't work.

I'm using Ionic 3, Ionic CLI 4.3.1, install the latest version of in app browser plugin.

EDIT: when installing ionic-native/in-app-browser, the following shows:

```
npm WARN ajv-keywords@2.1.1 requires a peer of ajv@^5.0.0 but none is installed.
You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 
(node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
+ @ionic-native/in-app-browser@4.17.0
added 1 package from 1 contributor and audited 6219 packages in 17.843s
found 6 vulnerabilities (1 low, 5 moderate)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Ionic info output:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.3.1 


Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.13.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 7
```

Error when build:

```
ionic cordova build android
> ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform android
'ionic-app-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[INFO] Looks like @ionic/app-scripts isn't installed in this project.

       This package is required for this command to work properly.

? Install @ionic/app-scripts? Yes
> npm i -D -E @ionic/app-scripts
npm WARN deprecated cryptiles@2.0.5: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated boom@2.10.1: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@2.1.1 requires a peer of ajv@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @ionic/app-scripts@3.2.0
updated 1 package and audited 6219 packages in 31.422s
found 6 vulnerabilities (1 low, 5 moderate)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
> ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform android
'ionic-app-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[ERROR] ionic-app-scripts command not found.
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `ionic info` ?

Comment: I have added that info

Comment: Try downgrading nodejs to version 8